# Записать определенную часть html страницы в файл

Tags: python, selenium, beautiful-soup

Использую Selenium + BeautifulSoup, всю html страницу я сохранил в файл с помощью кода ниже. Но как сохранить не всю страницу, а кусочек кода. Например, часть html страницы с классом `heading__name`?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
...
html_page = driver.page_source
with open("home_team_injuries.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(html_page)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    "https://www.soccerstand.com/ru/player/castrovilli-gaetano/ALBpOZPH/")
# между скобок вписываете URL или путь к html файлу
html_page = driver.find_element(
    By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.heading__name').get_attribute("outerHTML")
with open("home_team_injuries.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(html_page)
```

Comment: Проверил ваш код по этой странице, искал элементы (By.CLASS_NAME, 'spacer'). Записывает в файл только последний из всех.

Comment: Все верно. Автор задал конкретный вопрос, написав конкретную страницу и класс. Мой код был написан под конкретную страницу и класс соответственно. Для других элементов/классов/страниц нужен другой код.

Comment: В вашем случае вы можете попробовать код:
```elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'spacer')
with open("home_team_injuries.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
 for element in elements:
  file.write(element.get_attribute("outerHTML"))```

Answer (score 3):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
...
div = soup.select('.heading__name') #В кавычках можно вписать нужный класс или тег
with open("home_team_injuries.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(div.content) # .content выводит вместе с тегами .text просто текст внутри данного тега без дочерних элементов
```

Также в кавычках можно вписать иерархию дом модели html пример: 'body > .classname > a'
Подбираясь к нужному элементу
Если в html тегов с нужным классом несколько, тогда можно через цикл их прогнать и выбрать нужный кусок кода

Comment: Проверил ваш код на этой странице выдает ошибку AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'content'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()? Искал элементы div = soup.select('.spacer').

Comment: Возможно у вас в html имеется несколько элементов с классом '.spacer' тогда нужно переменную div прогнать через цикл так как .content и .text и подобные им не вызываются у list, set, tuple.